# How to create a new dataframe for each column by looping over the dataframe columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe named `data` with the following columns:

```
'ContextID', 'strategyname', 'Date', 'Time_ms', 'Time_Elapsed', 
'StepID', 'WfrCntSinceLastClean', 'Ar_Flow_sccm', 'BacksGas_Flow_sccm', 
'BacksGas_Prs_Torr', 'EscAct_Curr_A', 'EscAct_Volt_V',
'EscRF_P2P_Volt_V', 'Mano100mTorr_Prs_Torr'
```

with the columns from `Ar_Flow_sccm` each being a parameter.

I want to create a dataframe for each and every one of the parameter and the columns of the dataframes must be `ContextID, the parameter column ,StepID, Time_Elapsed`

I did write a function for it as follows:

```
def param(df, col_name):
    d = df.loc[:, ['ContextID', col_name, 'StepID', 'Time_Elapsed']]
    return d
```

and when I do

```
BacksGas_Flow_sccm  = param(data, 'BacksGas_Flow_sccm')
```

I get a dataframe named `BacksGas_Flow_sccm` that has the columns as
`ContextID, BacksGas_Flow_sccm ,StepID, Time_Elapsed`

I could do this for all the parameter columns, but is there an easy way to get this done? Maybe by using something like

```
for col in data.columns[7:]:
    'create the dataframes of the col'
```

**Edit:** A part of my dataframe:

```
 ContextID   strategyname   Date   Time_ms    Time_Elapsed   StepID    WfrCntSinceLastCount    Ar_Flow_sccm     BacksGas_Flow_sccm     BascksGas_Prs_Torr    EscAct_Curr_A    EscAct_Volt_V    EscRF_P2P_Volt_V         Mano100mTorr_Prs_Torr
    7289973 Speed2_Gas_Basics   2018-07-09  0 days 09:12:48.502000000   0.0 1   0   49.560546875    1.953125    1.00000001335143e-10    0.122100122272968   1.22100126743317    12.4542121887207    0.00263671879656613
    7289973 Speed2_Gas_Basics   2018-07-09  0 days 09:12:48.603000000   0.101   2   0   49.560546875    2.05078125  0.00244140625   0.0 0.0 12.4542121887207    0.00234375009313226
    7289973 Speed2_Gas_Basics   2018-07-09  0 days 09:12:48.934000000   0.43200000000000005 2   0   99.853515625    2.05078125  0.00244140625   0.0 0.0 12.4542121887207    0.00234375009313226
    7289973 Speed2_Gas_Basics   2018-07-09  0 days 09:12:49.924000000   1.4220000000000002  2   0   351.318359375   2.05078125  0.00244140625   0.122100122272968   2.44200253486633    12.4542121887207    0.00380859384313226
    7289973 Speed2_Gas_Basics   2018-07-09  0 days 09:12:50.924000000   2.422   2   0   382.8125    1.953125    1.00000001335143e-10    0.122100122272968   0.0 12.4542121887207    0.004321289248764511
    7289973 Speed2_Gas_Basics   2018-07-09  0 days 09:12:51.924000000   3.422   2   0   382.8125    1.7578125   1.00000001335143e-10    0.122100122272968   1.8315018415451 13.1868133544922    0.004321289248764511
    7289973 Speed2_Gas_Basics   2018-07-09  0 days 09:12:52.934000000   4.432   2   0   382.8125    1.7578125   1.00000001335143e-10    0.122100122272968   0.0 12.4542121887207    0.004321289248764511
    7289973 Speed2_Gas_Basics   2018-07-09  0 days 09:12:54.440000000   5.938000000000001   2   0   382.8125    1.85546875  1.00000001335143e-10    0.122100122272968   0.610500633716583   12.4542121887207    0.004321289248764511
    7289973 Speed2_Gas_Basics   2018-07-09  0 days 09:12:54.992000000   6.49    2   0   382.8125    1.7578125   1.00000001335143e-10    0.122100122272968   0.0 12.4542121887207    0.004321289248764511
    7289973 Speed2_Gas_Basics   2018-07-09  0 days 09:12:56.430000000   7.928000000000001   5   0   382.8125    9.08203125  0.13671875  0.122100122272968   1.8315018415451 12.4542121887207    0.00437011709436774
    7289973 Speed2_Gas_Basics   2018-07-09  0 days 09:12:57.440000000   8.938   5   0   382.8125    46.19140625 2.109375    0.122100122272968   3.05250310897827    12.4542121887207    0.00437011709436774
    7289973 Speed2_Gas_Basics   2018-07-09  0 days 09:12:58.440000000   9.938   5   0   382.8125    46.19140625 2.109375    0.122100122272968   0.610500633716583   13.1868133544922    0.00437011709436774
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with actual data because it's not clear what you want.

Comment: Short answer is yes, to your "something like" snippet. Just iterate, call your function on each column, and append to a list or dict. Assuming, of course, that I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: added a part of my df @cs95

Comment: @Junkrat "with the columns from Ar_Flow_sccm each being a parameter" , but `Ar_Flow_sccm` itself is a column..can you explain a little more. Thanks

Comment: @anky_91 yes, Ar_Flow_sccm is a column. I meant to say that all the column that are after Ar_Flow_sccm, are the important  parameters. `Ar_Flow_sccm, BacksGas_Flow_sccm` and so on  till `Mano100mTorr_Prs_Torr`

Comment: @Junkrat and you want to return all these columns between the specific columns? `['ContextID', all_columns_after_Ar_Flow_sccm, 'StepID', 'Time_Elapsed']` ??

Comment: For `Ar_Flow_sccm`, the df must have the following columns: `['ContextID', Ar_Flow_sccm, 'StepID', 'Time_Elapsed']`... For `BacksGas_Flow_sccm`, the df must have the following columns: `['ContextID', BacksGas_Flow_sccm, 'StepID', 'Time_Elapsed']` and so on. Each parameter must have a separate dataframe of their own with the second column being the parameter column

Comment: Yes, it does. But for that I have to manually define every column name manually, that's why I am looking for an option where in, maybe, using a loop will give me the output @anky_91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can change the func to:

```
def param(df, col_name):
    d= (df.loc[:, ['ContextID']+
        [col_name]+['StepID', 'Time_Elapsed']])
    return d
```

Then create a dict of dataframe, using [`get_loc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html)

```
d={'df_{}'.format(i):param(df,i) 
        for e,i in enumerate(df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc('Ar_Flow_sccm'):].columns)}
print(d)
```

This will save the dataframes in a dict. the keys will be named as `df_Ar_Flow_sccm` and so on.. and the values will have a df with columns such as :`['ContextID', 'Ar_Flow_sccm', 'StepID', 'Time_Elapsed']`

You can call each dict key to see the df example:

```
print(d['df_Ar_Flow_sccm'])
```

**Note**: `df.columns.get_loc('Ar_Flow_sccm')` returns `7`

Comment: @Junkrat not sure why i put the `enumerate` there but :`d={'df_{}'.format(i):param(df,i) for i in df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc('Ar_Flow_sccm'):].columns}` also should work